# Looking for a short story about two astronauts stranded on a beautiful, paradisiac planet/moon, until one of them goes missing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story about two astronauts stranded on a beautiful, paradisiac planet/moon, until one of them goes missing the next day. The remaining astronaut is perplexed at first, and fears the worst, until he goes missing as well.

Comment: That's pretty vague so far. Why don't you tell us everything you remember about the story, maybe somebody will recognize it. If there were only two astronauts, how can the last one "go missing"? Who is missing him/her? By the way are the astronauts men, women, humans, aliens, robots? How old is the story? How long ago did you read it?  Was it in English? Did you find out what happened to the missing astronauts, or was that left unresolved at the end of the story?

Comment: We love to answer questions like this, but we aren't super-sleuths and we need more help. There are thousands of stories about stranded astronauts, hundreds of stories about edenic planets. It would help a lot if you could provide **details** which might make your story different from the others. Any detail, howerer trivial or unimportant it may seem to you, may jog someone else's memory. Don't worry about spoilers. They are expected in story-ID questions: you give us all the spoilers you can think of, we try to find the story that matches.